# AJAX returning data error?

Tags: php, ajax

please, could you help me with this problem?:

I'm getting products sorted ASC or DESC by title or price. If I sort them ASC, there is no problem - I loop products in foreach and adding generated string into variable. But if products are sorted DESC, there is problem - I'm looping them via foreach but html is not adding into variable (I tried to print_r variable $products, so I know, it wasn't empty..) - I hope that if you look at code bellow, my question would be clear. Do you know, where might be problem? Thank you very much.

I also tried to call this code not via ajax, but go to the url of ajax script and behavior is same...

EDIT:
I tried to echo `$products_html` before adding `$products_html` into `$return['products_html']` and in `$products_html` is correctly generated html... I'm quite confused what does this mean...

EDIT 2:
when I print_r $return, it is all ok - products html is stored in $return['products_html']. Problem is, when I json_encode it. But I really don't know, where is the problem...

Here is code:

```
$products_html = '';
$products = $this->products_model->get_products_specified($filter); // here i load products into variable
foreach($products as $product){ // here i loop them
            $products_html .= view_loader('products/product_small', array('product' => $product), true); // view load returns html for product
        }
$return['products_html'] = $products_html;
        $return['params_url'] = base_url().'individual/'.generate_url_from_parameters($filter);
        $return['status'] = 1;
        $return['filter'] = $filter;
        echo json_encode($return); // echo for ajax return
```

Comment: Can you give us the value of $products right before the loop?

Comment: It's array of products. You can find it there (first is print_r $products, then is echo of $products_html and then is echo json_encode($return); ): http://beta.akomin.cz/ajax/individual/&cat=410&order_by=title&order=desc&p_527=0

Comment: @JanKožušník what error are you getting? Give more information.

Comment: I post it in my question.  **I tried to echo $products_html before adding $products_html into $return['products_html'] and in $products_html is correctly generated html... I'm quite confused what does this mean...**

Comment: We cannot tell what is wrong here. You say this code is unchanged, so it should work. The only thing you changes is `order by` in a query that is not posted at all. If we have the data of the array (the result of the query), then we can judge whether this could would work with that data. For now, we know nothing and you seem reluctant to give information.

Comment: What more should I answer? I told, where is my problem and also I post link where to find out example

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype for the field you are sorting is other than an Numeric datatype like varchar, then that might be the problem.

Comment: How do you mean it? Price is float, title is varchar(256)